# mathematical proof that if the vectors ⃗ and  all are normalized unit vectors

Tags: recommender-system, mathematica

In a vector space model when we are given a query as a vector ⃗ and documents 1
, 2 …, we usually rank
the documents in relevance to the query vector using cosine similarity. Show by a mathematical proof that if the vectors ⃗ and  all are normalized unit vectors (i.e., |⃗|) than the ranking by ordering the documents
with increasing euclidean distance from the query is always identical to the ranking of ordering the documents with decreasing cosine similarity.

Comment: Is this not a (self-)study question?

Answer (score 5):

Just notice that, if $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors, then
$$
  \Vert u-v\Vert^2=\Vert u\Vert^2+\Vert v\Vert^2-2 \langle u,v\rangle=2(1- \cos \theta),
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$. Therefore, in this case, ordering by Euclidean distance is the same as ordering by cosine dissimilarity.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but are you sure that a right answer ?

Comment: I don't care about the typo I just need the right answer

Comment: thank you sir I thankful your help